# How do I use a printed text output from one script as the command line argument for another?

Tags: python, api, command-line, command, google-translate

I have one python script that prints a mixture of stocks, headlines, my google calendar agenda for today, and the weather outside. I'm trying to figure out how to use this text output as the in-line argument for Matt Dyson's amazing Google translate, text to speech script: http://mattdyson.org/blog/2014/07/text-to-speech-on-a-raspberry-pi-using-google-translate/

Basically, I want my first script to be spoken every time the script is run.

I'm shooting for a single script that leaves the first "printing" script intact, as it's modular and just runs a bunch of execfile commands for other scripts.

I hope this makes sense!?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about passing the argument to a subprocess that calls Matt's script?

Like this;

```
import subprocess
...
textcommand = #command to call your script
myProcess = subprocess.Popen(textCommand.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
textOutput = myProcess.communicate()[0]
....
mattCommand = 'python matts_script.py ' + outputText
mattProcess = subprocess.Popen(mattCommand.split())
```

Edited based on OP input.

Comment: That's definitely closer to what I'm trying to do! Thank you. But what I'm really trying to do is take everything that PRINTS from my first script and have that be equal to the variable myText that you provided above.

Comment: You could call you script and grab its input. I edited my answer above. Check it out and let me know if that might work.